# Swift Firebase Snapshot query missing child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

I store some settings in firebase database and reach this settings from app. It's working fine with the first 3 settings, but when I tried to add a new one, I can't reach this.

**The code, what I use:**

```
    func getLanguage(){
    ref = DatabaseRef.settingsRef
    //ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let valueL = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        if (valueL?.count)! > 0 {
            self.lang = ((valueL!["lang"])! as? String)!
        }
     })
}
```

**DatabaseRef is a struct file to store all the references. settingsRef:**

```
static let settingsRef = Database.database().reference().child("events").child(event).child("settings")
```

When I run this method, I got this error code on *self.lang = ((valueL!["lang"])! as? String)!*

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Ofcourse I double checked my database structure, and the path, but I can't figure out what is the problem, because my settings db looks like this:

```
     "settings" : {
         "contLog" : "true",
         "lang" : "en",
         "showStat" : "true",
         "useGate" : "true"
  },
```

And the snapshot looks like this:

[image: snapshot]

PS: I know "true" is not bool, it's just for string test.

Comment: From the screenshot it's quite clear why the error occurs: there is no `lang` property in the snapshot. It is however from the code you shared unclear why there is no `lang` property. I'd do three things: 1) use a regular `observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent`, 2) check if the property exists before casting it (`if snapshot.hasChild("lang")`), 3) log the value. If this shows the correct result, the problem might be related to caching.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Yes, my problem is what you said, no lang in snapshot however it should be. I'll make a try with your suggestion.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I tried. 1, Changed to `ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in`. 2, `if snapshot.hasChild("lang")` added. 3, `print(self.lang)` and `else print("no lang")` added. Result: "no lang" in console.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure why that would be then. The code looks fine, as far as I can see. How certain are you that `settingsRef` is pointing to location that has the `lang` property online?

Comment: Shot in the dark here but your ref path may not be what you think it is. Try print(ref) just before the firebase call and see where it points to - it may be *event* is not correct and pointing to a path that does not contain the *lang* child.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: I was sure with the settingsRef, because I already used it with the other childs.
Jay: Same, I triple checked the path, and everything was ok..
Somehow the iOS stored older snapshot, and idk why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, it was a cache problem. 
When I deleted the app from my phone (and from simulator), and rebuild it, everything works fine. Somehow the iOS stored older snapshots..